# jQueryTools scrollable does not work with mousewheel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I just upgraded to jQueryTools 1.2.7 and jQuery 1.7.2. I needed a few extra features for the scrollable plugin. Now, mousewheel scroll for the vertical scrollables does not work, unless I make it to behave circular.

this code, which worked perfect with 1.2.5

```
$("#productscroll").scrollable({mousewheel:true, vertical: true});
```

It does not scroll. If I press "next", it reacts once and scrolls to the top. 
Peculiar.

This setup works, but then my list never stops, that is confusing.

```
 $("#productscroll").scrollable({circular:true, mousewheel:true, vertical: true});
```

Has anyone experienced this and know of a quick fix?

Comment: It seems that scrolling is very random when circular is set to true. Found a way to report a bug via github. The author's demo showed the same behavior, so should be easy for him to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is a bug. A possible fix is posted on GitHub.
Here's my post, the fix is in issue 766.
https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/790